# Unity3d seamless level loading

Tags: unity, loading, scene

I've read that application.loadLeveAdditiveAsync is a pro only feature. I'm looking for an asset that can do something similar. I would like to load assets based on the camera/player position. Ideally, it would be great to dispense with scenes entirely and just load information based on some distance value. This asset seems to be doing just that: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/8015 however I'm not sure if the author is active anymore, and recent customers are complaining about a serious bug.

Any recommendations about assets that allow for seamless, open world style transitions between scenes would be great. (using Unity 3D 5, basic version, and writing in c#).

Comment: `I've read that application.loadLeveAdditiveAsync is a pro only feature` That is incorrect.

Comment: Has this changed since unity 5? I just looked at another forum that confirmed that async functions are a pro only feature, but it was dated 2012

Comment: yes http://www.pcworld.com/article/2892314/unity-5s-new-full-featured-personal-edition-is-completely-utterly-free-to-use.html

Comment: wow that's incredible! I found a free asset which seamlessly loads scenes: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/38168, but I guess I'd be better off just learning loadleveladditiveasync. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application.LoadLevelAdditiveAsync is not a pro feature anymore.